# How do upload the Loader.io verification token in a Strapi app?

Tags: load-testing, strapi

We have an app built with Strapi, let's say, https://my-strapi-app.com

I want to load testing of the application

For that, I went with Loader.io

Now before loader.io can start sending the load to the app, I need to verify that the website belongs to me.

For that Loader.io ask me to place a verification token that is accessible via one of the following links:

1. https://my-strapi-app.com/loaderio-c56xxxxx.txt
2. https://my-strapi-app.com/loaderio-c56xxxxx.html
3. https://my-strapi-app.com/loaderio-c56xxxxx/

What steps can I take to make the verification token accessible at any one of the above URL?

Answer (score 0):

Although it's a bit late,
and I have no experience with Strapi (I use Flask / Python),
but if anyone still looking for the answer,
here is my "Flask" way solution:

```
@app.route("/your-loader-io-token/"), methods=["GET"])
def loader_io_verify():
  return send_from_directory("/path-of-the-txt-file", "your-loader-io-token.txt", as_attachment=True)
```

Basically, it will just download the "your-loader-io-token.txt" file, when someone access url "https://your-website.com/your-loader-io-token/".

That's it :D !